# Step over last line in PyCharm in debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I often run into the problem where I want to step over the final line in my code in the PyCharm debugger, but I can't because PyCharm just stops the execution.

Here's a minimal example - let's say I want to inspect the value of `z`:

```
x = 5
y = 7
z = x * y  # here's the breakpoint
```

If I set set a break-point on the last line, it hasn't been executed yet, so I cannot inspect `z`, but if step to the next line the execution stops.

The workaround that I'm using is to just add a 'dummy' line at the end, so I can stop there, like so:

```
x = 5
y = 7
z = x * y
pass  # here's the breakpoint
```

Is there a more 'elegant' way of doing this?

Comment: No, if you want to see the state of your script after the last line of a routine or script, you will need to add another line - there's nothing to show for the debugger, because there's no next statement for the debugger to wait on, in a sense, what you're asking to see never really exists. Or at least, not in a state where a debugger can get at it.

Comment: Makes sense, I thought there's maybe there's some 'smart' built-in functionality to do this

Comment: It's not a crazy question, but consider this: if there is no line of code after the assignment to `z` that actually makes use of `z`, the value of `z` won't matter - it's about to get thrown away and nothing makes use of it. So, if you need to know the value of `z`, there's likely to be follow-up code that uses `z`, and you should be able to break on that.

Comment: I guess I agree, but I often encounter this problem during writing code, when my function/script/etc is not ready, so I just like to stop at the last line and 'explore' how to go further having the state of all the variables - but maybe that's just not the right use of a debugger. What I can do is use a jupyter notebook style coding environment where I just execute this code, have all the variables and then continue working on them - I just don't like that, but that's just preference

Comment: I think it's worth reconsidering your coding practices - it's good that you want to make sure code you wrote so far works, but code is only as good as the program it's a part of. You'd need to know what is going to happen next, so you may as well write some of it already. There's no arguing taste, but as an experienced programmer, I don't see many situations where there's a real benefit to debugging before working on some sort of continuation - and where it's absolutely needed, a `pass` is better than having the entire language be a bit more inefficienty to accommodate.